# where is the absl namespace declared?

Tags: unit-testing, googletest, googlemock

I am trying to implement an "asynchronous" Google Unit Test. I'm following the example in [gMock Cookbook](https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/github.com/google/googletest/+/HEAD/googlemock/docs/cook_book.md#testing-asynchronous-behavior). For whatever reason my code can't seem to find `absl::Notification` and gives me the error `Use of undeclared identifier 'absl'`. What do I need to include?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like they are using Abseil, "an open-source collection of C++ library code designed to augment the C++ standard library."

https://github.com/abseil/abseil-cpp

I am surprised that the book wouldn't mention this somewhere in the "Installation" chapter of the book (I don't own a copy myself).

UPDATE: I noticed on the [GoogleTest](https://github.com/google/googletest#coming-soon) site a notice that they are planning to take a dependency on Abseil "soon".